# Tomcat servlet the requested resource is unavailable

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I am very unfamiliar w/ servlets and have been asked to write a simple a simple program on tomcat 7 using java. I wrote a very simple hello world program and haven't been able to get it running and need some help.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
/**
 *
 * @author Michael
 */
public class JavaServletTest extends HttpServlet {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws IOException, ServletException
{
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    out.println("<html><body>");
    out.println("HELLO WORLD!!");
    out.println("</body></html>");


}}
```

I have it in my classes folder under my WEB-INF folder and the tomcat application manager shows that it is running.

So i have my folders like webapps/JavaServletTest/WEB-INF/classes
web.xml is in the JavaServletTest folder with the WEB-INF folder
and in classes I have the JavaServletTest.class with my source code. I the application to load
my web.xml looks lik

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application     2.3//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>JavaServletTest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>JavaServletTest</servlet-class>
</servlet>


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JavaServletTest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/testServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I've been trying to load this at 
xxx.xxxxxx.xxx/JavaServletTest/testServlet 
but have not been having any success.

Comment: What is the name of the WAR file which you deployed?  You should be trying to access `http://xxx.xxxxxx.xxx/Name_of_WAR/testServlet`

Comment: Is your `web.xml` inside the `WEB-INF` folder?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen what is a WAR file? (I am very new to this)

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen no it is outside in directory as the WEB-INF

Comment: Move it inside the `WEB-INF` folder.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen thanks that worked but now i'm getting different errors thanks

Comment: I'll convert my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `web.xml` file needs to be **inside** the `WEB-INF` folder instead of next to it.

If it's not in the right location, Tomcat won't parse it and your URL patterns will not be correctly configured.

If you're using the Servlet 3.0 (or higher) API, you could also configure your servlet by annotating it with the [`@WebServlet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html) annotation, and you won't need the `web.xml`:

```
@WebServlet("/testServlet")
public class JavaServletTest extends HttpServlet {
    /* ... */
}
```